# Adding a setter for foreground color for all elements in a UserControl, using XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

My UserControl contains a number of Labels. In XAML I want to define a setter that allows clients to set the Foreground for all of these at once.

---

*Source code: (simplified)*

Under Page.Resources:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="customItemTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <MyControlLib:XYControl Unit="{Binding XYUnit}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XYMultiplier}" Width="16"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

In Page contents:

```
<ListBox x:Name="XYZList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource customItemTemplate}">
    <!-- Set Foreground to "Red" for all items -->
    <!-- For XYControl this is the TextForeground property -->
    <!-- For TextBlock this is (naturally) the Foreground property -->
</ListBox>
```

(Read the XAML comments for the WPF greatness I want to achieve)

Of course, `customItemTemplate` is used in more than one place in the page, with a different color.

How simple could it be in WPF!

Answer (score 4):

If you want the value to be able to be set externally by users of the UserControl, you can define a new `DependencyProperty`, which can then be set on any instance of the control.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelForegroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "LabelForeground",
    typeof(Brush),
    typeof(MyUserControl),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));

public Brush LabelForeground
{
    get { return (Brush)GetValue(LabelForegroundProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LabelForegroundProperty, value); }
}
```

You can then create a default Style for Label inside the UserControl that binds to this value:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyUserControl}}, Path=LabelForeground}" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Any instance of the control can then set its own value that will be applied to its own Labels:

```
<MyUserControl LabelForeground="Red"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this example will help you.
A style is defined in a parent node so it takes effect on all the labels, and in the code behind it's beeing replaced by a new style.

XAML:

```
 <StackPanel x:Name="root">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style  TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Label>AAA</Label>
    <Label>BBB</Label>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Change Color</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var x = new Style();
        x.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, Value = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green) });

        root.Resources.Clear();
        root.Resources.Add(typeof(Label), x);
    }
```